# Typescript Interface make optional

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have an interface like this:

```
export interface IDefaultAction extends Object {
  type: string
  (dispatch: Dispatch<IStateObject>, getState: () => IStateObject, extraArgument: any): any;
}
```

is there any way I can make the second line in the interface optional?
`(dispatch: Dispatch<IStateObject>, getState: () => IStateObject, extraArgument: any): any;`

and if so, how?

and also if possible please explain or point me to the right documentation which explains what does this interface mean:

```
interface IA {
  ():any;
}
```

I just can't figure out this syntax

```
():something;
```

Thanks!

edit:

I am trying to extend this:

```
export type ThunkAction<R, S, E> = (dispatch: Dispatch<S>, getState: () => S,
                                    extraArgument: E) => R;
```

in my own interface:

```
export interface IDefaultAction {
  type: string;
}
```

but optionally,
so the only thing I could think of, is to modify the original(ThunkAction) and make all inside it optional, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> please explain or point me to the right documentation which explains what does this interface mean:

The `IA` interface is a function interface. It defines [a "function type"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html).

```
interface IA {
    (): any;
}

const exampleImplementation: IA = () => "";
```

The `(): any` defines the function type's signature, which includes the function's parameter list and return type. The function type `IA` takes no parameters and returns an `any`.

> is there any way I can make the second line in the interface optional?

The second line is a function signature, which means that the interface defines a function type. Its function signature takes two parameters and returns an `any`.

```
export interface IDefaultAction extends Object {
  type: string;
  (
    dispatch: Dispatch<IStateObject>,                  // paramater 1
    getState: () => IStateObject, extraArgument: any   // parameter 2
  ) : any;                                             // return type
}
```

While interfaces support [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html), interfaces do not support optional function signatures.